# How do I stop webpages from scrolling when I use Mousekeys?

Tags: windows-7

When I use Mousekeys to navigate through webpages and I scroll down fast, the page continues to scroll down though I have stopped pressing "Arrow down"...or is this happening because I have Stickykeys turned on too?  If that's the problem is there a way to use both features while stopping the "auto-scroll"?

Win 7 Pro.
IE 9.

Comment: Are you using a wireless keyboard?

Comment: No, it's wired...